# roots of higher derivatives of exponential

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, polynomials, elementary-proofs

Consider the Gaussian function $f(z)=e^{-z^2}$ which has no zeros on the complex domain. Let $D$ denote derivative w.r.t. the variable $z$.

> **Question.** Is it true that $D^nf(z)=0$ has only real roots that are simple?
>   If so, any slick proof?

Comment: Plan of action: $D^nf=P_n(z)e^{-z^2}$ for some polynomial $P_n$. Calculate the first few, and look up the coefficients at oeis.org.

Comment: I calculated the first 200 and they all have only real roots. $P_0=1$ and $P_{n+1}=-2zP_n+P'_n$ (derivative wrt $z$ of course). But how do you look up a sequence of polynomials at oeis?

Comment: The idea I guess is to recognise the polys as e.g. Euler-Jacobi polynomials of the 12th kind or whatever, and then appeal to the classical result that they only have real roots. But I don't know how to look for a list of polys on oeis as this is a 2-d array.

Comment: You can look up two-dimensional arrays in oeis listing them by rows, e.g., 1,1,1,1,2,1,1,3,3,1 will get you http://oeis.org/A007318 "Pascal's triangle read by rows". http://oeis.org/A060821 gives coefficients of Hermite polynomials.

Comment: Oh *many* thanks @GerryMyerson --  I did not know that trick

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The (physicists') [Hermite polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials) are

$$ H_n(x) = (-1)^n e^{x^2} D^n e^{-x^2}$$

And their roots are real.  For that you don't need to know they are Hermite polynomials: just Rolle's theorem.  See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104845/the-roots-of-hermite-polynomials-are-all-real).

Answer (score 10):

I've found a slightly different argument.

If $f_m(z)=\left(1-\frac{z^2}m\right)^m$ then $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}f_m(z)=e^{-z^2}$ uniformly on every compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Hence, the same holds for $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}D^nf_m(z)=D^ne^{-z^2}$. On the other hand, $D^nf_m(z)$ has only real zeros. Therefore $D^ne^{-z^2}$ can not have non-real zeros, by [Hurwitz's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)).

Answer (score 9):

There are several complete characterizations of real entire functions whose all derivatives have all roots real: a) this is a closure of polynomials with the same property,
and b) this class is represented by the formula
$$f(z)=cz^me^{-az^2+bz}\prod_{k}\left(1-\frac{z}{z_k}\right)e^{z/z_k},$$
where $a\geq0$, $b,c$ are real, $m\geq 0$ is an integer and $z_k$ real, with
$$\sum\frac{1}{|z_k|^2}<\infty.$$
This is a parametric description: each such function is represented by this formula,
and each function represented by this formula has the stated property.
This class of function has a standard name: Polya-Wiman class.

These results are due to Wiman, Polya, Hellerstein and Williamson.
For recent generalizations and survey, see
 arXiv:math/0510502.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to skin this cat. Most are presented in the excellent survey "[Zeros of entire Fourier transforms](https://www.dcce.ibilce.unesp.br/%7Edimitrov/ProfRusev/EJA_Paper_24_02_11/Dim_Rus_main.pdf)" by
Dimitar K. Dimitrov and Peter K. Rusev with an account of the historical development. Jensen's contributions are particularly interesting to me with the emphasis on Appell polynomial sequences--the Hermite polynomials are the only set of orthogonal Appell polynomials.